mTLS call using axios in node.js fails with '400 No required SSL certificate was sent'
I'm trying to perform an oAuth2 token request using axios in a node.js program, currently using the following code. The oAuth server is returning 400 Bad Request, No required SSL certificate was sent. I've verified all of the certificates and other inputs to the call, and all of the same inputs work fine with a similar cURL command. The call that is failing:
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const https = require('node:https')
const options = {
    cert:  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `..${path.sep}certs${path.sep}mycert.crt`)),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `..${path.sep}certs${path.sep}mykey.key`)),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `..${path.sep}certs${path.sep}ca.crt`))
}

const agent = new https.Agent(options)
const axios2= axios.create({ agent })
const ident = "Basic " + Buffer.from("MY KEY" + ":" + "MY SECRET").toString("base64")
const data = `Id=<my id>&Key=<my key>&grant_type=client_credentials`
const url = `https://${process.env.HOST}/oauth/v1/token?scope=rs-read`

const response = await axios2({    //   <--- fails with 400, No certificate sent
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': ident,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data
})

The options containing the certificates are all valid Buffer objects. I'm pretty sure the problem is my misunderstanding of the axios call, since I know my inputs are correct - the following cURL command works perfectly using the same certificates, data, and headers:
curl -X POST
    --cert ./mycert.crt
    --key ./mykey.key
    --cacert ./ca.crt
    https://<host>/oauth/v1/token?scope=rs-read
    -H "Authorization: Basic blahajh0M1dWN1paamNZRzblahblah=="
    -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    -H "Accept: application/json"
    -d "Id=<my id>&Key=<my key>&grant_type=client_credentials"

I'm hoping someone who has successfully used axios for mTLS can spot where the axios call is wrong, or a cURL expert might tell me what it does differently under the hood.  Thank you.

The option for an https agent is httpsAgent not (just) agent
